# Remove objects that have duplicate keys

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

My code...

```
class Inbox {

    var user = "name"
    var pmsg = "label"
    var match = ""
    var resim = "photo"
    var userID = ""
    var distance = ""
    var updated = ""
    var isAttendingNow = ""
    var isAttendingNowText = ""


    init(user : String, pmsg: String, match: String, resim: String, userID : String, distance: String, updated: String, isAttendingNow: String, isAttendingNowText: String) {

      self.user = user
      self.pmsg = pmsg
        self.match = match
        self.resim = resim
        self.userID = userID
        self.distance = distance
        self.updated = updated
        self.isAttendingNow = isAttendingNow
        self.isAttendingNowText = isAttendingNowText

    }


}

var arrayOfRels: [Inbox] = [Inbox]()
```

My goal is to remove duplicate items for userID key.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should use `Set` or `NSOrderedSet` so that you dont have duplicate objects. You can implement `hashable` and check equality for `userID` in that for adding these in Set.

Comment: What dictionary? Your title is "Remove items with duplicate values from dictionary" but I don't see a dictionary anywhere. You appear to have an array of `Inbox` objects. You want to remove objects that have duplicate userID keys?

Comment: @DuncanC chill man. I edited it. all ok?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Hashable`

```
class RRR : Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int = 0

    static func == (lhs: RRR, rhs: RRR) -> Bool {

     // in your case set only userID

       return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.age == rhs.age
    }

    var name:String

    var age:Int

    init(name:String,age:Int) {

        self.name = name

        self.age = age
    }

}
```

//

```
let arr = [RRR(name: "qqq", age: 12) ,RRR(name: "qqq", age: 12) , RRR(name: "hhhh", age: 12) , RRR(name: "ppppp", age: 12) ]

let set = Array(Set(arr))

print(set)  // [ RRR(name: "qqq", age: 12) , RRR(name: "hhhh", age: 12) , RRR(name: "ppppp", age: 12)]
```

Comment: When I use it in cellforrowat of tableview, let set = Set(self.arrayOfRels)
        let release = set[indexPath.section] I get Cannot subscript a value of type 'Set<Inbox>' with an index of type 'Int' error

Comment: Use **let set = Array(Set(self.arrayOfRels))**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set to figure out which useIDs are unique:

```
func filteredRels(source [Inbox]) -> [Inbox] {
   var keys: Set<String> = []
   return source.filter {
      if keys.contains($0.userID) {
        return false 
      } else {
        keys.insert($0.userID)
        return true
      }
   }
}
```

(Banged out in the editor, so it might need some minor cleanup.)

Comment: What do you mean. I gave you code that should do exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func uniqueOrdered() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        return reduce([Iterator.Element]()) { $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1] }
    }
}


class Inbox: Hashable {
    ...
    ...
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
        return lhs.userID == rhs.userID
    }
}


arrayOfRels.uniqueOrdered()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a couple of lines using a set:

```
var unique = Set<String>()
arrayOfRels = arrayOfRels.filter{unique.insert($0.userID).inserted}
```